# How the class methods are implemented in javascript?

Tags: inheritance, scope, javascript

I am learning one library, seeing an example and i don't understant how is it done?
Within functions of class, "this" variable contains all the methods of the class.
Outside only public methods are available.

Protected methods are more interesting. They are available only in the inherited class.
How does it work?

See an example from the documentation below:

```
/**
  * A-class
  */
var ClassA = AWeb.class({
   public : {
      /**
        * A-class constructor
        */
      constructor : function() {
         /* Private variable */
         this.variable1 = "A";
         this.calls = 0;
      },

      /**
        * Function returns information about the object
        */
      getInfo : function() {
         this.incCalls();

         return "variable1=" + this.variable1 + ", calls=" + this.calls;
      }
   },
   protected : {
      /**
        * Protected function
        */
      changeVariable1 : function( value ) {
         this.variable1 = value;
      }
   },
   private : {
      /**
        * Private function
        */
      incCalls : function() {
         this.calls++;
      }
   }
});
/**
  * C-class
  */
var ClassC = AWeb.class({
   extends : ClassA,
   public : {
      /**
        * B-class constructor
        */
      constructor : function() {
         this.super();
         this.changeVariable1( "C" );
      },

      /**
        * Function returns extended information about the object
        */
      getLongInfo : function() {
         return this.incCalls !== undefined ? "incCalls visible" : "incCalls undefined";
      }
   }
});
/**
  * Main project function
  */
function main() {
   var a = new ClassA(),
       c = new ClassC();

   alert(
      "a instanceof ClassA: " + (a instanceof ClassA) + "\n" +
      "a instanceof ClassC: " + (a instanceof ClassC) + "\n" +

      "a.getInfo " + (a.getInfo ? "exists" : "undefined") + "\n" +
      "a.getLongInfo " + (a.getLongInfo ? "exists" : "undefined") + "\n" +
      "a.changeVariable1 " + (a.changeVariable1 ? "exists" : "undefined") + "\n" +
      "a.getInfo()=" + a.getInfo() + "\n\n" +

      "c instanceof ClassA: " + (c instanceof ClassA) + "\n" +
      "c instanceof ClassC: " + (c instanceof ClassC) + "\n" +

      "c.getInfo " + (c.getInfo ? "exists" : "undefined") + "\n" +
      "c.getLongInfo " + (c.getLongInfo ? "exists" : "undefined") + "\n" +
      "c.changeVariable1 " + (c.changeVariable1 ? "exists" : "undefined") + "\n" +

      "c.getInfo()=" + c.getInfo() + "\n" +
      "c.getLongInfo()=" + c.getLongInfo()
   );
}
```

If it helps: http://a-web.me/tutorial_javascript.html

Comment: Please clarify your question. If you are interested in Encapsulation principle (http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Object_Oriented_Programming#Compile_Time_Enforced_Access_Restrictions) or in how it works particular in JS (http://javascript.crockford.com/private.html & http://nemisj.com/protected-javascript/)

Comment: I can hardly believe it works at all. Either they are hacking horribly around, or it they simply fake it. I might be able to say more when I see the implementation of `AWeb.class`, but I couldn't find the code online. Please post the library itself that you want to have explained (the relevant parts, or at least link the code), not an example of its use :-)

Comment: Sorry for the inexact question. I know the principles of inheritance in javascript.
I am interested in the implementation of inheritance in the specified library. It works, I tested it.

Library is free, but it has a closed code, it is not possible to read it.
It works in all browsers.

I wrapped the specified code into the html page, please look.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry for the inexact question. I know the principles of inheritance in javascript.
I am interested in the implementation of inheritance in the specified library. It works, I tested it.

Library is free, but it has a closed code, it is not possible to read it.
It works in all browsers.

I wrapped the specified code into the html page, please look.

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>

<html>
<head>
    <title>Sample project</title>
    <!-- Styles -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://a-web.me/styles/default/a-web.css" >
    <!-- Scripts -->
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://a-web.me/scripts/a-web.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        /**
          * A-class
          */
        var ClassA = AWeb.class({
           public : {
              /**
                * A-class constructor
                */
              constructor : function() {
                 /* Private variable */
                 this.variable1 = "A";
                 this.calls = 0;
              },

              /**
                * Function returns information about the object
                */
              getInfo : function() {
                 this.incCalls();

                 return "variable1=" + this.variable1 + ", calls=" + this.calls;
              }
           },
           protected : {
              /**
                * Protected function
                */
              changeVariable1 : function( value ) {
                 this.variable1 = value;
              }
           },
           private : {
              /**
                * Private function
                */
              incCalls : function() {
                 this.calls++;
              }
           }
        });
        /**
          * C-class
          */
        var ClassC = AWeb.class({
           extends : ClassA,
           public : {
              /**
                * B-class constructor
                */
              constructor : function() {
                 this.super();
                 this.changeVariable1( "C" );
              },

              /**
                * Function returns extended information about the object
                */
              getLongInfo : function() {
                 return this.incCalls !== undefined ? "incCalls visible" : "incCalls undefined";
              }
           }
        });
        /**
          * Main project function
          */
        function main() {
           var a = new ClassA(),
               c = new ClassC();

           alert(
              "a instanceof ClassA: " + (a instanceof ClassA) + "\n" +
              "a instanceof ClassC: " + (a instanceof ClassC) + "\n" +

              "a.getInfo " + (a.getInfo ? "exists" : "undefined") + "\n" +
              "a.getLongInfo " + (a.getLongInfo ? "exists" : "undefined") + "\n" +
              "a.changeVariable1 " + (a.changeVariable1 ? "exists" : "undefined") + "\n" +
              "a.getInfo()=" + a.getInfo() + "\n\n" +

              "c instanceof ClassA: " + (c instanceof ClassA) + "\n" +
              "c instanceof ClassC: " + (c instanceof ClassC) + "\n" +

              "c.getInfo " + (c.getInfo ? "exists" : "undefined") + "\n" +
              "c.getLongInfo " + (c.getLongInfo ? "exists" : "undefined") + "\n" +
              "c.changeVariable1 " + (c.changeVariable1 ? "exists" : "undefined") + "\n" +

              "c.getInfo()=" + c.getInfo() + "\n" +
              "c.getLongInfo()=" + c.getLongInfo()
           );
        }
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Does anyone have any suggestions?